# How to produce DLL from a working VC++ project?

Tags: c++, c, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a VC++ project on Visual Studio 2017, the project so far is compiling and everything is fine, but I need to convert it in a DLL, but I can't find the correct way for doing this, does anyone can help me out pointing me to the right direction?

Comment: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a C/C++ project in VS, you can choose the project to be a dynamic link library; the build process will create the appropriate DLL file in the folders Debug or Release.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Info]

Right click project, properties, General, Configuration Type.
But this isn't what you only have to do, you have to use [DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain), exports etc.